# Error when deploying MVC 4 app with Ninject to Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, ninject

I have written a MVC 4 application using Visual Studio 2012 RC. It uses Ninject as a dependency injector and it works without any problems on my local machine using Azure Emulator. The application targets .NET 4.0. However, when I deploy it to the Azure as a Web Role I am getting this Exception:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +117
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +247
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +84

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Poller.WebUI.Controllers.QuestionsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +247
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +85
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +270
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +66
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +161
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +405
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

I don't want to add parameterless constructor to the QuestionsController, because I need DB repository there, which is passed as a constructor parameter. This parameter should be correctly filled by Ninject.

Does anybody has any idea what could possibly be a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well.  I want to say in our case, we had to be sure that we were using Windows 2008 R2 for our MVC app and not Windows 2008 SP1.  You can update your config files to `OS="2"` or just log in to the admin panel, select your web role and click upgrade OS.  Cannot say for sure if this is your issue or not, but it was for us on an MVC 3 site.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. Still the same exception. But thanks for trying!

Comment: Ok - have you/can you remote into your webrole instance and check to ensure that all of the relevant ninject assembilies were deployed correctly?

Comment: I connected via remote desktop and checked the DLLs in bin folder. It looks OK to me. There is Ninject.dll and many other assembilies. What else can cause different behavior in the cloud and in the local enviroment?

Comment: When you test locally, are you using the compute emulator or just normal IIS Express/VS Web server?

Comment: I am using Azure compute emulator. It starts application at localhost:81 and everything works perfectly.

Comment: I will try stripping down the application part by part to check where exactly is the problem. I will start with removing Ninject and harcoding every dependency.